# Duplicating an array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, array

This code returns an array that consists of two copies of the input array.

Can you review this algorithm?

```
//input: [1, 2, 3]  output: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]              
function duplicate(arr) {
 let copy = [];
 for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  copy.push(arr[i])
  }
 return copy.concat(arr)
 }
```

Comment: Just use `return arr.concat(arr)`

Comment: Or the ES6+ way `return [...arr, ...arr];`

Comment: [Javascript ... duplicate an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3978492/463206).   A good SO thread & starting place for looking into whys and wherefores of array duplication variations.

Answer (score 3):

The alternative approaches in the comments `return arr.concat(arr);` and `return [...arr, ...arr];` are good replacements.

However, if you wrote this as part of a course, you should consider the following:

- Your indentation is off, this is rule 1 in writing code: indent it
- You are missing a semicolon after `copy.push(arr[i])`
- In such a small function, I would have declared `i` up top in that `let` statement